# `<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>` not give me all my categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-list-categories

`<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>` not give me all my categories.

I use `<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>` in my `footer.php` file to display my categories but in home page show only two categories and in inner single posts show post's related category and in pages show nothing.
even I use `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after each `WP_Query`

please help me

Comment: Did you try : wp_list_categories() ?

Comment: wp_list_categories() only prints "categories"

Comment: Yes, but that's your goal, right ? "to display my categories"

Comment: your code `wp_list_categories()` was my solution but I forget to set the args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('exclude=22&title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = get_categories($args);
$html       = '<ul>';
foreach($categories as $cat){
$html .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($cat->term_id);.'"';
$html .= '<h2>'.$cat->cat_name.'</h2>'; 
$html .= '</a></li>';
}
$html .= '';
return $html;`
```

in your function